# Instantiated sprites from prefab invisible but there

Tags: parent-child, unity-game-engine, invisible

*Note: Incase you get confused, playership_1 is the enemy prefab, it just won't let me change the name*

I am making a laser defender game in my online course (2D) and so what we are doing is instantiating, and/or spawning enemies as children of positions that are marked by gizmos. When I start the game, it looks like this: 
[image]
When I start the game, I only see the spaceship and the black background. When I pause and go into the scene, this is what I see:
[image]

I have checked the z-value, even though I don't have a background. What is wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a closer look at **playerShip1_blue** in your image the scale is set to `0 0 0`. So my guess is that all your instantiated gameobjects has the same scale.

```
transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f,1f,1f);
```

Add this code above to the `GameObject` you instantiated and you should see the playerships in your game

**Why** this is happening and a better solution to the problem is to stop using `transform.parent = transform;` and use  `transform.SetParent(transform);`

I found a good explanation here and please read it http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/868484/why-is-instantiated-objects-scale-changing.html